# How to filter output of all existing stored procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have many stored procedures in my SQL Server database, and about 90% of them return a table. The database has been created for storing data of a C# project.

In a scenario, from application side when I call a procedure, I want to be able to apply some general filter to process the output. For example get top 100 records of the output. This filter should be done for every procedure, so I have built a single and common static class which it is only point that calls the procedure in my app. Then I filter every output in there and return it.

Ok this work for me but it is not efficient, because database returns redundant rows which they will be filtered in app side.

I decided to improve the job. I'm thinking about migrating the filter to be applied on the database side, but without modifying any existing procedure.

My idea is that I create a `RunnerProcedure` in the database which gets the procedure name and its parameters, runs it, applies my general filter and finally returns the resulting output.

For example my general filter might be:

```
select top 100 * from output
```

So in this approach, I have to implement something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RunnerProcedure 
AS 
    @ProcedureName nvarchar(max),
    @ProcedureParameters dbo.ProcedureParametersTableType READONLY 
BEGIN
 ... 
 // @output = execute @ProcedureName with @ProcedureParameters 
 Select top 100 * from (@output)
 I don't have any idea in implementation! please help.
 ...
END
```

I talked my idea to explain what I want exactly. If it is possible please let me know how. Complete it please. Or if it's not possible, please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

go for a [stored procedure created in managed code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

build a c# library that contain the code you already have, put it on the server and then 'wrap' it in a stored procedure as documented in the linked msdn page.

all the calls from the application will be routed through the 'c# stored procedure' that will filter the records on the server.

i don't see a big advantage from load perspective because the full recordset is produced anyway and the server is now responsible for output cutting but the amount of data transferred on the network would be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something below

```
SELECT * INTO #temptable 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=loclhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'exec procedurename')

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM #temptable
```